# Relational Operator Implementation Dilemma

Tags: c++

I'm in the process of designing several classes that need to support operators `!=`, `>`, `<=`, and `>=`. These operators will be implemented in terms of operators `==` and `<`.

At this stage, I need to make a choice between inheritance¹ and forcing my consumers to use `std::rel_ops`² "manually".

[1] Inheritance (possible implementation):

```
template<class T> class RelationalOperatorsImpl
{
    protected:
    RelationalOperatorsImpl() {}
    ~RelationalOperatorsImpl() {}

    friend bool operator!=(const T& lhs, const T& rhs) {return !(lhs == rhs);}
    friend bool operator>(const T& lhs, const T& rhs) {return (rhs < lhs);}
    friend bool operator<=(const T& lhs, const T& rhs) {return !(rhs < lhs);}
    friend bool operator>=(const T& lhs, const T& rhs) {return !(lhs < rhs);}
};

template<typename T> class Foo : RelationalOperatorsImpl< Foo<T> >
{
    public:
    explicit Foo(const T& value) : m_Value(value) {}

    friend bool operator==(const Foo& lhs, const Foo& rhs) {return (lhs.m_Value == rhs.m_Value);}
    friend bool operator<(const Foo& lhs, const Foo& rhs) {return (lhs.m_Value < rhs.m_Value);}

    private:
    T m_Value;
};
```

[2] `std::rel_ops` glue:

```
template<typename T> class Foo
{
    public:
    explicit Foo(const T& value) : m_Value(value) {}

    friend bool operator==(const Foo& lhs, const Foo& rhs) {return (lhs.m_Value == rhs.m_Value);}
    friend bool operator<(const Foo& lhs, const Foo& rhs) {return (lhs.m_Value < rhs.m_Value);}

    private:
    T m_Value;
};

void Consumer()
{
    using namespace std::rel_ops;

    //Operators !=, >, >=, and <= will be instantiated for Foo<T> (in this case) on demand.
}
```

I'm basically trying to avoid code repetition. Any thoughts as to which method "feels" better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you considered using [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/utility/operators.htm), and having your class inherit from `boost::less_than_comparable<T>` and `boost::equality_comparable<T>`? It is akin to your first suggestion, with some pros and cons. Pros: avoids code duplication; Cons: creates a dependency on boost.

Since boost is a very common C++ library (if you don't use it already, you should seriously consider start using it), the con factor is dimmed.

Comment: That's an excellent suggestion. Boost never ceases to surprise me. I'd like to hear from others before I accept an answer, though. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think `std::rel_ops` is quite nice, but there's one thing to consider first: `std::rel_ops` provides operators as template functions that accept two parameters of the same type.  Because most conversions (including e.g. arithmetic promotions and user-defined conversions) are not performed when template argument deduction occurs, this means that you would not be able to use any of these additional operators (e.g. `!=`) with such conversions.

E.g. if you have a class `MyInt` that attempts to behave like a regular integer, you might have written conversion functions/constructors or templated operators so that you can do

```
MyInt x, y;

x < 5;
9 == x;
```

However,

```
x > 5;
30 <= x;
```

won't work (with `std::rel_ops`) because the two arguments are of different types, so template argument deduction will fail.